# htaccess -> site is not working work anymore

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

With the htaccess below the site is working fine, but when i rewrite all extensions .php to no .php the site is not working anymore. So now i want to rewrite a few urls to no .php

How do i do that? i can only find parts wich rewrite all scripts

This is what i have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove trailing slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# remove index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /(.*)index\.php/?([^\?\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2 [L,R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]*)(\.php)?(\?*)$ index.php/$1$3 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

rewriterule ^untitled.php http://www.bijschipholparkeren.nl/untitled [R=301,L]